# ATmega64 needs to be reset after Power Up

Tags: arduino, avr, reset

I am using an ATmega64A for my project with ESP8266 and RFM75. But the ATmega64 hangs on power up and I have to pull reset low to make my code work. I'm using an external 8 MHz crystal.

I have connected all VCC and GND pins properly with 0.1 µF capacitors on each VCC PIN. The RESET pin is pulled high with 10 kΩ resistors and 10 µF capacitors are connected between RESET and GND (I have tried 0.1 µF capacitors as well).

I need a some kind of help to get out of this issue. All comments or suggestion will be appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**
My Schematic attached here.
[image: ATmega64 Schematic.]

I have measured voltage level on RESET PIN on power-on condition.

[image: RESET PIN voltage on power on.]
[image: RESET PIN voltage on power on]

**EDIT 2**:
Only LED Blinking Code works well on the same hardware, I have checked so many times by switching the supply ON/OFF. I thing Code have some issues.
I'm trying to figure it out.

**EDIT 2:**
I have flashed Simple LED blinking code on start up before I start ESP8266 or RFM Initialization. I have a Debug option in my code as well. ATmega64 UART1 is used as Debug Terminal. I have tried flashing LED before Debug Initialization. Led Blinking works like charm!
I have a Function in Debug Terminal to print banner on start up. It prints Date time of compile and reboot causes and a version of code. when I have commented the function , my code started working fine. I have tested many time on different boards by the issue disappear from then. here the function which I have removed.

```
    static void PrintBanner(void)
{
    unsigned char status = MCUCSR;
    unsigned char moreThanOne = 0;

    printf_P(PSTR(CMD_LINE_MSG_WELCOME));
    printf_P(PSTR("Firmware: v%S [Compiled on "__DATE__" "__TIME__"]\r\nBoot cause: "), PSTR(APP_VERSION));

    if(status & (1 << PORF))
    {
        printf_P(PSTR("Power On"));
        MCUCSR &= ~(1 << PORF);
        moreThanOne = 1;
    }
    if(status & (1 << EXTRF))
    {
        if(moreThanOne)
            printf_P(PSTR(", "));
        printf_P(PSTR("External"));
        MCUCSR &= ~(1 << EXTRF);
        moreThanOne = 1;
    }
    if(status & (1 << BORF))
    {
        if(moreThanOne)
            printf_P(PSTR(", "));
        printf_P(PSTR("Brown-out"));
        MCUCSR &= ~(1 << BORF);
        moreThanOne = 1;
    }
    if(status & (1 << WDRF))
    {
        if(moreThanOne)
            printf_P(PSTR(", "));
        printf_P(PSTR("Watchdog"));
        MCUCSR &= ~(1 << WDRF);
        moreThanOne = 1;
    }
    if(status & (1 << JTRF))
    {
        if(moreThanOne)
            printf_P(PSTR(", "));
        printf_P(PSTR("JTAG"));
        MCUCSR &= ~(1 << JTRF);
        moreThanOne = 1;
    }

    printf_P(PSTR(" Reset.\r\n"));
}
```

What would be the cause for the RESET issue of the ATmega64 with this piece of code?
Does it because of fetching data from program memory to print over UART?
Still I'm trying to go to root cause for this issue. 
If anyone have any idea about this kindly throw some light on it.
Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to see some of your setup code or at least an overview. It sounds like your code is running into an unexpected state during startup. The quick and dirty (and not recommended) solution might be to have the MCU loop (empty for loop) a few thousand times on startup up, in order to wait for everything to stabilize.

Comment: Taher - I can think of a few potential hardware-related causes for this behaviour. However to consider those potential causes efficiently, you would need to (a) supply a complete, correct schematic & photos of the hardware; (b) list what test equipment you have available e.g. oscilloscope? Or only DMM? (c) explain the history of the design e.g. did a previous prototype work? If so, what has changed since that design? (d) explain what troubleshooting you have done so far e.g. have you tried running just a simple "blink LED" program in the MCU and disconnecting everything else from the MCU?

Comment: It's highly likely that your power supply rises too slowly. You can add a supply supervisor (brownout detector) like the MAX809 (http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MAX809S-D.PDF) to ensure consistent startup. These early ATMega's had the POR set at only about 1.5 V (as opposed to BOD set at 2.5 V), so if the power supply then rose from that level slowly it's possible the startup delay is too short and the processor hangs.

Comment: @Jack - Agreed (+1), this is one of the potential issues I considered, and it's why I asked about the availability of a 'scope, in order to measure that power supply rise time. When the OP reveals the history of events which I asked for, it might also contain data points which are relevant (e.g. perhaps a previous prototype worked with different power supply). Let's hope the OP replies with some updates and data...

Comment: @SamGibson: a) Sure I will provide complete schematic, right now I'm not able to do that.b)I have DMM, DSO, Oscilloscope available here. c) Yes previous prototypes worked well. at that time i was running CPU at 5V, now CPU is running at 3V3. that is the only change. I didn't change components or schematic but PCB Design in later prototypes. also this RESET issue, in new prototype, observed very often. Some times it works correctly some time need external reset.

Comment: @SamGibson: d) I just added Crystal and changed Fuse bits and decoupling Capacitors and RESET capacitor. I don't have tested different Code on Hardware like Blink LED, but will do that and will update soon.

Comment: @JackCreasey: I beg your pardon ,but can you please explain me this better?

Comment: On the ATMega's you have two very important reset conditions....those set by power on reset (Vpot) which on rising power is about 1.4 V ...when above this threshold the power on timing (t(TOUT)) will run. The processor VCC however needs to be at least 2.5 V on the '64L and 3.6 V   on the '64. If VCC is below these levels then the processor may not run ...it may hang. REad the datasheet around Table 19 Reset Characteristics for more detail ....and especially Note 2. ...if you supply does not rise quickly enough you can hang on powerup.

Comment: @JackCreasey Thank you so much, will look at that and will come back here.

Comment: @TaherKawantwala - Thanks. Although those answers were missing some info (so I did not completely understand the fine details), a brief analysis is that you have a near-ideal troubleshooting situation: previous prototype worked, but this one has your "often needs manual reset" symptom. Therefore you can compare the working and failing boards to find the bug(s) caused on the updated design. You said "I didn't change components" but your other comments say that you did. Anyway, if your work with *Jack* is not successful, there are troubleshooting techniques which can be applied. Good luck!

Comment: Try removing reset capacitor *and* resistor altogether from the circuit. Leaving reset pin floating will cause POR without any influence (and should be supported configuration). Reset pin is having internal pull-up of 30-60 kOhm.

Comment: @Anonymous I've removed Cap and RES from a RESET PIN, still problem is there. It works sometime, but some time I have to pull RESET LOW to make micro controller run.

Comment: Taher, then you may choose to take scope measurement of the power transition when device is being powered on, and if you do not find anything special there, apply for Atmel support. Interesting I do not see how to open a support ticket with them, if I would be a developer it would be one of major showstoppers in using their products. Probably you need to log into "my Atmel" to be able creating support tickets.

Comment: Do you have a serial link or anything else applying a signal to an I/O pin before power on?  That kind of thing can partially back-power a processor through the protection diodes and cause power-on to not really be a true power-on.

Comment: Have you changed the brown out level fuse? If it's set at 4V still it will cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

1. AVRs have clock startup delay fuses (SUT1/SUT0 for ATmega64) - check if problem happens at different settings of the startup delay.
2. Use brownout detection (also a fuse setting).
3. Try adding a busy-wait loop at the beginning.